# What is the difference between $path and $PATH (lowercase versus uppercase) with zsh?

Tags: zsh, variable, path, array

In [FreeBSD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD) 12, using the [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) shell, I noticed this difference when looking at `$path` (lowercase) versus `$PATH` (uppercase).

```
echo $path
```

> /sbin /bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/home/freebsd/bin

```
echo $PATH
```

> /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/home/freebsd/bin

One output is delimited by SPACE character, the other by COLON character.

➥ Why the difference?

Are these two different, separate variables? Or does the lowercase/uppercase trigger some kind of trick or meaning I do not know about?

Is this a `zsh` feature? Or a feature of FreeBSD?

Comment: Aside: In any POSIX-compliant shell, variable names with any lowercase characters are guaranteed safe for application use (not to silently modify shell or system behavior when changed). This is one of the places where zsh's decision to only follow the standard where it makes sense to them can make headaches for script authors, because the standardized guarantees don't apply.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy do you have a link to the part of the standard where it says any of that about the lower and upper case variables? Thanks.

Comment: @mosvy, https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html -- read it keeping in mind that shell and environment variables share a single namespace (setting the a shell variable updates the value of any existing like-named environment variable; setting an environment variable initializes shell variables). The specific lines: *The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.*

Comment: @CharlesDuffy That doesn't apply here. Setting `path` inside `zsh` will not update any `path` envvar: `path=junk zsh -c 'echo $path; path=garbage; /usr/bin/printenv path'`.

Comment: @mosvy, you've convinced me that it doesn't violate the letter of the standard. The *spirit*, on the other hand, would make `for path in "$dir"/*` reflexively safe-to-write code.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

That's a feature of [`zsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_shell) inherited from [`csh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_shell)/[`tcsh`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/tcsh).

The `$path` *array* variable is *tied* to the `$PATH` *scalar* (string) variable. Any modification on one is reflected in the other.

In `zsh` (contrary to `(t)csh`), you can tie other variables beside `$PATH` with [`typeset -T`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Shell-Builtin-Commands.html#index-typeset). It's conventional, but not mandatory, to use an uppercase name for the colon-separated scalar and the same name in lowercase for the array. While colon is the default separator, other separators can be used (for instance newline to tie a multi-line string to an array, or comma to tie a csv row to an array)

In recent versions of `zsh`, `typeset -p PATH` or `typeset -p path` shows the link between the two variables:

```
% typeset -p path
typeset -aT PATH path=( /home/chazelas/bin /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin )
```

That's useful in that it makes it easier to add remove components or loop over them.

Doing a `typeset -U path` to make the elements *unique* also helps keeping the `$PATH` variable clean (something similar can be achieved in `tcsh` with `set -f`).

For completeness, `fish` and `yash` are two other shells that can treat `$PATH` as an array, though in their case, that's not via a separate lowercase variable.

In `fish`, [variables whose name ends in `PATH` are treated as lists implicitly split/joined on colons](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#path-variables), so `set PATH /foo /bar` and `set PATH /foo:/bar` are equivalent there.

In `yash`, exporting an array to the environment results in the value of the environment variable containing the elements joined with a colon. So you can do `PATH=(/foo /bar)` there. Note that when importing `$PATH` from the environment upon start, `yash` does not automatically create it as an array.